# Remove non working hours from time series data

Tags: python

I am trying to remove non working hours from time series data.

I have used

```
PrimaryBookD=PrimaryBookC[PrimaryBookC['Time'].dt.dayofweek <5]
```

to remove weekends, which worked well. I am now trying to have the data from 7am to 5pm. I have tried

```
PrimaryBookE=PrimaryBookD[PrimaryBookC['Time'].dt.hour > 7 ]
```

but I am not sure how to format it so that it presents the time between 7 am and 5pm instead of 24hrs.

Thank you for your help!

This an example of the data I have been using

```
            Time                                A      B           C    
7908    2021-07-12 00:00:00.035812792+00:00 0.74900 1000000.0   0.74905
7909    2021-07-12 00:00:00.050670938+00:00 0.74900 1000000.0   0.74905
7910    2021-07-12 00:00:00.065535015+00:00 0.74900 1000000.0   0.74905
7911    2021-07-12 00:00:00.120588579+00:00 0.74900 2000000.0   0.74905
7912    2021-07-12 00:00:00.125803018+00:00 0.74900 4000000.0   0.74905
```

Comment: Please provide additional details like the *Data* you're working with or a *Reproducible Example*, and the errors you're facing

Comment: *"but I am not sure how to format it"* how should the format look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you understand your question correctly you try to select the data which is between 7:00 and 17:00.

This looks to me like a simple multi conditional selection. Something like this should do the trick:

```
newdf = PrimaryBookD[(PrimaryBookC['Time'].dt.hour > 7) & (PrimaryBookC['Time'].dt.hour < 17)]
```